# How to redirect from all subdomains to a php file with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there a way, using .htaccess, to redirect all users that entered to a subdomain to the main domain to a specific php file? for example, if you enters to `http://mypage.example.com/`, so you'll rediract to `http://example.com/website.php?name=mypage&using=subdomain`. If you'll type `http://mypage.example.com/contact.php`, you'll rediract to `http://example.com/website.php?name=mypage&page=contact&using=subdomain` and if you'll type some additional info (`?action=send#buttom`) it will stay (if I'm not mistaking, `[QSA]`)

Comment: Do you want a visible redirect from user's browser?

Comment: @Robert no, I want the user to think that this is a real subdomain.

Comment: We presume you have a wildcard DNS entry setup for subdomains to point to `example.com`?

Comment: Are both domains on same host and pointing to same `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: @anubhava, the subdomain doesn't really exist.

Comment: Well subdomain has to exist first otherwise you can't reach to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but I just used Wild Card (I'm not sure that it is the name). What is does it is when you write a subdomain, no metter what subdomain, it redirects you to the main domain, and then using .htaccess I continued...